# Using Regular Expression to define a yes/no logic in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, regex, selenium, selenium-ide

Basically I want an IDE line that says:

If $variable matches XXXXX format then make value 'DoesVarMatch'=Yes

This is so I can then do conditional gotoIf statements if the variable matches the regexp. Ultimately I want to do this with a date (validate as dd/mm/yyyy) and email variable, but I am starting with a simple regular expression to get the logic worked out.

I have tried the following (which does not work):

```
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>'Green' == /[Gg]reen/</td>
    <td>GreenTrue</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>stop</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>GreenTrue</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I also tried to use javascript (which also didn't work, I expected a True value to be returned):

```
<tr>
    <td>runScript</td>
    <td>var re = /[Gg]reen/.test('Green'); return re.test('Green');</td>
    <td>Colour</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${Colour}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

The following execute correctly but I don't seem to be able to use them to define yes/no logic:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyEval</td>
    <td>'Green'</td>
    <td>regexp:[Gg]reen</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>'Green'</td>
    <td>regexp:[Gg]reen</td>
</tr>
```

I appreciate any insights into using Selenium to use the regexp or javascript to define a variable I can use to do the logic test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. If anyone has any suggestions to improve what I have here please feel free to comment. Basically instead of creating a value to then do the gotoIf statement I used the regex validation itself to determine the gotoIf statement.

```
<!--Basic Colour testing-->
<tr>
    <td>verifyEval</td>
    <td>'Green'</td>
    <td>regexp:[Gg]reen</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>'Green'</td>
    <td>regexp:[Gg]reen</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>Colour</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>javascript{ var re = /[Gg]reen/g; re.test(storedVars.Colour);}</td>
    <td>GreenTrue</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>stop</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>GreenTrue</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>stop</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a heads up. The way you're using the verify/assertEval command is true, to a sense of it equates correctly. However not in terms of the parameters

```
verifyEval | logicaltest | outcome
```

So if your logical test wasn't `==` then you would need a better syntax. For example

```
verifyEval | 'Green'!==/[Gg]reen/ | false/true
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Selenium Developers

I found the answers to getting a Boolean result to use in this problem.  First, upgrade to Selenium 2.9.1 or higher.  That gives you access to the JavaScript function "test".  Then you can code the following that works to give you a Boolean result that you can use in your "gotoif".  Here is an example of one that I used recently.

1. Prompt the user for a number from 1-11.
2. Place the prompt variable into a number object. (Not sure if this is necessary?)
3. Define the regular expression into a variable.
4. Lastly, use the JavaScript "test" function to produce a Boolean response placed in the "results" variable.
5. This leaves you a "results" field to determine your "gotoif".

Here is the code.

```
<tr>
    <td>showPrompt</td>
    <td>Please select a number between 1-11 only!!!</td>
    <td>userAnswer</td>
<\tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>new Number(storedVars['userAnswer'])<\td>
    <td>nbrAnswer</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript{var regExpTester = /^[1-9][0-1]?$/; regExpTester.test(storedVars.nbrAnswer);}</td>
    <td>results</td>
<\tr>
```